# FM Demodulation Issue: Output Signal Anomalies

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am working on a project that involves FM demodulation of a signal. I've encountered an issue where the `quad_demod` function I'm using isn't producing the expected results, despite working well in other environments such as MATLAB. Specifically, when attempting to demodulate a live signal captured from a sound card (sampled at 48 kHz), the output signal appears distorted and unusual.

I expect the FM demodulation process to produce accurate results, similar to those achieved in other instances like MATLAB:

[Fig. 1 quad_demod() works fine in Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIa4L.png)

However, when I try to demodulate a signal in my Python project, it looks distorted:

[Fig. 2 weird result of quad_demod() in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmMop.png)

```
def quad_demod(signal):
    """
    quadrature demodulates input signal
    by https://www.notblackmagic.com/bitsnpieces/afsk//#digital-modulation-implementation
    implemented into python by Madeus, 2023

    input: frequency modulated signal
        dtype = ndarray
        ndim = 1 (complex) or ndim = 2 (real)

    output: quadrature demodulated signal
        dtype = ndarray
        ndim = 1
    """
    if not len(signal):
        print("Error: quad_demod len(length) = 0")
        return

    # adjust input format
    if np.ndim(signal) == 1:
        signalI = np.real(signal)
        signalQ = np.imag(signal)

    elif np.ndim(signal) == 2:
        if np.shape(signal)[1] > np.shape(signal)[0]:
            signal = np.transpose(signal)
        signalI = signal[:, 0]
        signalQ = signal[:, 1]

    else:
        print(f"Error: Worng dim of input signal! (dim = {np.ndim(signal)})")
        return

    # iteration of demodulation
    iDelayLine, qDelayLine = np.array([0, 0]), np.array([0, 0])
    y = np.empty([len(signalQ)])
    for i, _ in enumerate(signalQ):
        # Calculate delta values
        dI = signalI[i] - iDelayLine[1]
        dQ = signalQ[i] - qDelayLine[1]

        # Multiplication part
        mI = iDelayLine[0] * dQ
        mQ = qDelayLine[0] * dI

        """
        if sometimes encounters an overflow, better use Int32 for full data or use smaller gain to ant.
        """
        y[i] = mI - mQ

        # Shift delay line samples
        iDelayLine[1] = iDelayLine[0]
        iDelayLine[0] = signalI[i]
        qDelayLine[1] = qDelayLine[0]
        qDelayLine[0] = signalQ[i]

    return y
```

Comment: Create simple signal, like low freq sine, modulate it and check your algorithm on it. Easier to find problems when dealing with easy example.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code and now it works!

```
def quad_demod(signalI=None, signalQ=None, IQ=None):
"""
quadrature demodulates input signal
by https://www.notblackmagic.com/bitsnpieces/afsk//#digital-modulation-implementation
implemented into python by Madeus 2023

input: frequency modulated signal
    dtype = ndarray
    ndim = 1 (complex) or ndim = 2 (real)

output: quadrature demodulated signal
    dtype = ndarray
    ndim = 1
"""
# if not len(signal):
#     print("Error: quad_demod len(length) = 0")
#     return

if IQ is not None and signalI is None and signalQ is None:
    signalI = np.real(IQ)
    signalQ = np.imag(IQ)

elif IQ is None and signalI is not None and signalQ is not None:
    pass

else:
    print(f"I:{type(signalI)}, Q:{type(signalQ)}, IQ:{type(IQ)}")
    raise ValueError("quad_demod: Input Error")

# iteration of demodulation
iDelayLine, qDelayLine = [0, 0], [0, 0]
y = np.empty([len(signalQ)])
for i, _ in enumerate(signalQ):
    # Calculate delta values
    dI = signalI[i] - iDelayLine[1]
    dQ = signalQ[i] - qDelayLine[1]

    # Multiplication part
    mI = iDelayLine[0] * dQ
    mQ = qDelayLine[0] * dI

    """
    if sometimes encounters an overflow, better use Int32 for full data or use smaller gain to ant.
    """
    y[i] = mI - mQ

    # Shift delay line samples
    iDelayLine[1] = iDelayLine[0]
    iDelayLine[0] = signalI[i]
    qDelayLine[1] = qDelayLine[0]
    qDelayLine[0] = signalQ[i]

y[0] = y[2]
y[1] = y[2]
return y
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).